# ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: PG::InternalError expected "]" to end datum

Tags: ruby, postgresql, activerecord

I'm a newbie to Ruby and using ActiveRecord.

I'm trying to create a record (i.e. a new instance of a class) using ActiveRecord. I've already created and ran the migration, which created this file:

```
class CreatePeople < ActiveRecord::Migration
    def change
        create_table :people do |t|
            t.string :first_name
            t.string :last_name
            t.datetime :birthdate
        end
    end
end
```

This is my model file with a class called Person in it:

```
class Person < ActiveRecord::Base
end
```

I went to the terminal and started the IRB console with the command "rake console." I tried the inputs: `person = Person.new` and `person = Person.create(first_name: "Dave", last_name: "Smith")`. Either input just gives me this error message:

```
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: PG::InternalError: ERROR: expected "]" to end datum, 
but got "0 0 0 0 ]}) :location 2634}}
```

ETA (full error message):

```
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: PG::InternalError: ERROR: expected "]" to end datum, 
but got "0 0 0 0 ]}) :location 2634}} :targetList ({TARGETENTRY :expr {VAR 
:varno 4 :varattno 1 :vartype 19 :vartypmod -1 :varcollid 0 :varlevelsup 0 
:varnoold 4 :varoattno 1 :location 2224} :resno 1 :resname schemaname 
:ressortgroupref 0:resorigtbl 2615 :resorigcol 1: resjunk false} 
{TARGETENTRY :expr {VAR :varno 3 :varattno 1 :vartype 19 :vartypmod -1 
:varcollid 0 :varlevelsup 0 :varnoold 3: varattno 1 :location 2257} :resno 2 
:resname tablename :ressortgroupref 0 :resorigtbl 1259 :resorigcol 1 
:resjunk false} {TARGETENTRY :expr {FUNCEXPR :funcid 1645 :funcresulttype 19 
:funcretset false :funcvariadic false :funcformat 0: funccollid 0 
:inputcollid 0 :args ({VAR :varno 3: varattno 5 :vartype 26 :vartypmod -1 
:varcollid 0 :varlevelsup 0 :varnoold 3 : varoattno 5 :location 2305}) 
:location 2289} :resno 3 :resname tableowner :ressortgroupref 0 :resorigtble 
0 :resorigcol 0 :resjunk false} {TARGETENTRY :expr {VAR :varno 6 :varattno 1 
:vartype 19 :vartypmod -1 :varcollid 0 :varlevelsup 0 :varnoold 6 : varattno 
1 :location 2340} :resno 4 :resname tablespace :ressortgroupref 0 
:resorigtble 1213 :resorigcol 1 :resjunk false} {TARGETENTRY :expr {VAR 
:varno 3 :varttno 13 :vartype 16 :vartypmod -1 :varcollid 0 :varlevelsup 0 
:varnoold 3 :varoattno 13 :location 2373} :resno 5 :resname hasindexes 
:ressortgroupref 0 :resorigtble 1259 :resorigcol 13 :resjunk false} 
{TARGETENTRY :expr {VAR :varno 3 :varattno 21 :vartype 16 :vartypmod -1 
:varcollid 0 :varlevelsup 0 :varnoold 3 :varoattno 21 :location 2410} :resno 
6 :resname hasrules :ressortgroupref 0 :resorigtble 1259 :resorigcol 21 
:resjunk false} {TARGETENTRY :expr {VAR :varno 3 :varattno 22 :vartype 16 
:vartypmod -1 :varcollid 0 :varlevels up 0 :varnoold 3 :varoattno 22 
:location 2445} :resno 7 :resnmae hastriggers :ressortgroupref 0 :resorigtbl 
1259 :resorigcol 22 :resjunk false}} :withCheckOptions <> :returningList <> 
:groupClause <> :havingQual <> :windowCaluse <> :distinctClause <> 
:sortClause <> :limitOffset <> :limitCount <> :rowMarks <> :setOperations <> 
:constraintDeps <>})”; length = 1

    LINE 2:     FROM pg_tables
    :     SELECT TABLENAME
          FROM pg_tables
          WHERE schemaname = ANY (current_schemas(false))
    from C:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.1/lib/active_record
/connection_adapters/postgresql/database_statements.rb:147:in ‘async_exec’
    from C:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.1/lib/active_record
/connection_adapters/postgresql/database_statements.rb:147:in ‘block in query’
    from C:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.1/lib/active_record
/connection_adapters/abstract_adapter.rb:473: in ‘block in log’
    from C:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.1/lib
/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:20:in ‘instrument’
    from C:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.1/lib/active_record
/connection_adapters/abstract_adapter.rb:467:in ‘log’
    from C:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.1/lib/active_record
/connection_adapters/postgresql/database_statements.rb:146:in ‘query’
    From C:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.1/lib/active_record
/connection_adapters/postgresql/schema_statements.rb:91:in ‘tables’
    from C:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.1/lib/active_record
/connection_adapters/schema_cache.rb:90:in ‘prepare_tables’
    from C:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.1/lib/active_record
/connection_adapters/schema_cache.rb:22:in ‘table_exists?’
    From C:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.1/lib/active_record
/model_schema.rb:230:in ‘table_exists?’
    from C:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.1/lib/active_record
/attribute_methods/primary_key.rb:97: in ‘get_primary_key’
    from C:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.1/lib/active_record
/attribute_methods/primary_key.rb:95:in ‘reset_primary_key’
    from C:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.1/lib/active_record
/connection_adapters/postgresql/
    from C:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.1/lib/active_record
/attribute_methods/primary_key.rb:73:in ‘primary_key’
    from C:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.1/lib/active_record
/model_schema.rb:234:in ‘attributes_builder’
    from C:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.1/lib/active_record
/model_schema.rb:254: in ‘_default_attributes’
    from C:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.1/lib/active_record
/core.rb:273:in ‘initialize’
    from C:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.1/lib/active_record
/inheritance.rb:61:in ‘new’
    from C:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.1/lib/active_record
/inheritance.rb:61:in ‘new’
```

Comment: Sorry, you're right that was just a typo in Stack Overflow, not in my actual code.

Comment: your migration and AR class look fine. To launch the console, use `rails console` (or `rails c` in short) instead of `rake console`. Your problem seems to stem from your PG setup, not rails. What is the exact SQL statement sent to the DB ?

Comment: I don't have rails installed. This is for Ruby on Rails class and we aren't working in Rails yet. This task involves creating a database in the command terminal using ActiveRecord, which uses the rake Ruby gem. .new and .create are methods for rake. It's like Step 3 here: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_basics.html. I'm just trying to create an entry with person = Person.new. That's all I'm sending through ActiveRecord to the PG server.

Comment: Added an extra section in the error message, if that helps. The error message is actually a lot longer; I'll see if I can type it all out.

Comment: I installed PostgreSQL and someone else gave me the templates I needed for ActiveRecord (gemfile, rakefile, config file). Then I used the rake ruby gem to create and run the migration with the commands: bundle exec rake db:create and bundle exec rake db:migrate. I'm supposed to create entries in the database using IRB and the rake console next but that's when I got this error.

Comment: Added full error message in the question

Answer (score 1):

As noted by m_x, there was an issue with the PG setup. There was no issue with ActiveRecord itself. In order to resolve this specific StatementInvalid Error, a full uninstall and reinstall needed to be performed for PostgreSQL.

It seemed like PostgreSQL's data folder got corrupted in some way. Just uninstalling using the Control Panel or the PostgreSQL uninstaller did not uninstall PostgreSQL completely. Specifically, PostgreSQL was not being uninstalled from the registry. This partial uninstall prevented a new data folder for PostgreSQL from being created with the correct bin and lib directories within it. These steps needed to be followed to get PostgreSQL to be uninstalled completely:

1. Uninstall PostgreSQL from control panel or the PostgreSQL
   uninstaller from within the PostgreSQL directory.
2. Delete PostgreSQL directory folder
3. Run CCleaner to make sure old PostgreSQL registry keys are deleted. (free download available here: http://www.filehippo.com/download_ccleaner)
4. Download and reinstall PostgreSQL

Comment: The uninstaller explicitly mentions that you need to delete the data directory, which is likely the only step required to correct that issue.